# Error message: "range is not defined" when creating a sorting script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to use part of the code from [this auto-sorting script](https://gist.github.com/mikebranski/285b60aa5ec3da8638e5#file-keep-column-sorted-in-google-sheets-gs) to make a script that when you press a button on the spreadsheet, it sorts the list.
However, I keep getting an error message: "ReferenceError: range is not defined"

Here is the code:

```
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;
var ASCENDING = false;
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 9;
range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);

function sortID(sheet) {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Report Log");
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}
```

Also I should probably mention im really new to scripting in google sheets.

Comment: Thanks. Ill try that. two moments

Comment: I did that and it didnt seem to help. Im not entirely sure what you mean though.
Here's what I did: https://imgur.com/a/LtWAvR9

Comment: In this line `range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 0);` as you can see you use `range` but `range` is not defined anywhere, hence the pretty descriptive error message: `range is not defined`.

Comment: How should I define it somewhere else?

Comment: do you know what is your goal? which range do you want to get?

Comment: Nevermind I found it out. Thanks!